# Django send email with gmail SMTP only works on localhost (fail on DigitalOcean)

Tags: django, smtp, registration, digital-ocean, django-allauth

I'm using Django allauth to manage the my user registration. When the user create an email account, he receive a confirmation email. He cannot login to the site if the email is not confirmed. All work well on localhost (the email is sent, the confirmation works, and if the user try to connect before having confirmed the email, the connection fails with the appropriate error message).
But the problem comes when I try my app on my digitalocean server. The mail is not sent and the user can connect even if the email is not confirmed. My Django email settings are:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-username@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Where does the problem comes from? I think it's something with my digitalocean server but I'm not sure at all.

**EDIT:**

I tried to allow access to my Google account using external application with this link https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha but it doesn't change anything.

I tried to change SMTP port to 465 like described here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server, but same thing, no change.

Comment: did you find the answer? I am having the same problem :(

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem where it worked on localhost but not when the app was live.
Here's the fix,

1. go to google's [2step-verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/) and set that up
2. go and sign up for app password [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)
3. then they ask to select an app and a device, (i chose custom for both), then press generate.
4. the password they give, put that in

   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'app-password'

   and you should be all good to go.